# Why is `mixlibshellout` not executed from the specified location?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

This seems to execute the command:

```
begin
  cwdkernel =  Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/src/ap-kernelmodule-10*')
  cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("build cmd", :cwd => 'cwdkernel')
  cmd.run_command
  log 'run'
end
```

Is the syntax wrong? The command does not run.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match a path with the first five characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887262/how-to-match-a-path-with-the-first-five-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed `'cwdkernel'` as a string, not the variable named `cwdkernel`.