# How to match a path with the first five characters

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have to reach the location `/var/log/acpchef/commv123`, where `123` can change to `456`.

I tired `Dir.glob`. I need `/var/log/acpchef/commv***`. My execution will be in `mixlibshellout`.

```
begin
  cwd_kernel = Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/commv***')
  cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("commandrun", :cwd => cwd_kernel)
  cmd.run_command
  log 'run'
end
```

Comment: `Dir['/var/cache/acpchef/commv*']` (only one wildcard) should work.

Comment: Can you show an example.I am new to ruby and chef

Comment: Welcome on Stackexchange Janani! Could you edit your question to become more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match a filenename with the first five characters and anything after that:

```
Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/commv*') 
# will match /var/cache/acpchef/commv12345abcdxyz123456
```

This will match a filename with any three extra characters:

```
Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/commv???') 
# will match /var/cache/acpchef/{commv123, commv456, commvabc, ...}
```

This will match a filename with three numbers:

```
Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/commv[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
# will match /var/cache/acpchef/commv{123, 234, 456, 999, ...}
```

Also, your example is not correctly using the block syntax and has `begin..end` without `rescue`, which does essentially nothing. It should become:

```
Dir.glob('/var/cache/acpchef/commv???').each do |cwd_kernel|
  cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("commandrun", :cwd => cwd_kernel)
  cmd.run_command
  log 'run'
end
```

`Dir.glob` returns an [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html), which is a collection of the results. `Array.each` returns an [Enumerator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html), which basically is an object that runs the following block of code with a new value as many times as there are new values available, which means you can use it to run the same block of code for all the results of `Dir.glob`. The value is passed to the block through the `|block_argument|` syntax.

The [`begin`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/rescue.html) keyword in ruby is used to capture errors:

```
begin
  # do something that generates an exception
rescue => exception
  # handle the exception
end
```

A `begin` without `rescue`, `ensure` or `else` does nothing.

Also, this is quite similar to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52812166/681520).